# Trigger Selenium Tests cases in the post build event

Tags: selenium, continuous-integration, tfsbuild, post-build-event

I have a requirement where i have to trigger the selenium test cases for UI testing in the post build event of the TFS build definition (i.e., after the the files have been deployed in the higher environment using udeploy) as part of CI (continuous integration) pipeline. Any ideas on how to achieve this?

Comment: Try to use any of the `CI` tools, e.g. **Jenkins**

Comment: Which version of TFS are you using?

Answer (score 0):

It seems you are using the old XAML build, and want to use post build script to run selenium test. If this is the case, you could invoke the command line, like MSTest, to your script and check in the script. Then, you can specify the script path in your XAML build process template. Check more information about Run a script in your XAML build process at website:
 https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/dn376353%28v=vs.120%29.aspx

But I strongly recommend you to upgrade your TFS to 2015 version and later so that you could use the new build system. In new build system, it is easy and flexible to run selenium test. You can get start from the website below:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/build-release/test/continuous-test-selenium